# Show that there are infinitely many primes congruent to 4 modulo 5

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Use $A=5p_1p_2...p_r +4$ to show that there are infinitely many primes congruent ro 4 modulo 5. What goes wrong? In particular, what happens if you start with 19 and try to make a longer list?

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to approach this question. This is not a subject I am strong in. But this is what I have so far:

Okay, so if I start with $p_1=19$, then 5(19)+4=99. 99 is 3*3*11, none of which are congruent to 4(mod5). Is this what they mean by "what goes wrong?" What should my next step be?

Comment: It means that this technique does not produce a proof. There may be an elementary proof of this fact, but not by this method.

Comment: So basically, when I use 19 for p1, it gives me 99 which does not produce more primes congruent to 4(mod5). thus I'm not able to make a longer list as the question describes?

Comment: see this   http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf  I will need to think about it, all I see is that we can easily prove infinitely many primes equivalent to $\pm 1 \pmod 5,$ I'm not sure how we get the $-1$ separated out.

Comment: I don't think I need to go through and prove there are infinitely many primes, to my understanding, I just need to show what the problem is when using A. So, would it be enough to say that the problem I run into is that there is no proof produced?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are only finitely many primes congruent to $4$ modulo $5$: $p_1, \dots p_n$.

Let $k$ be a natural number such that $4^k5 > (p_1 p_2 \dots p_n)^2$.

Now consider $m = 4^k5 - (p_1 \dots p_n)^2 > 0$

If $p$ is a prime divisor of $m$, $p$ is odd and we have $(p_1 \dots p_n)^2 \equiv 4^k5 \pmod{p}$, so $4^k5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Thus we have $ 1 = \left(\frac{4^k5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{(2^k)^2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)= \left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$ By quadratic reciprocity $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ and the quadratic residues modulo $5$ are $1$ and $4$, so $p \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ or $p \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, but the latter is impossible as $p$ is not in the list $p_1, \dots ,p_n$, as $p_i \mid m \Rightarrow p_i \mid 5 \lor p_i \mid 2$, which is absurd. So $p \equiv 1 \pmod 5 $. As this is true for every prime divisor, we must have $m \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. But by construction $m \equiv -1 \pmod 5$, a contradiction.

So there are infinitely many primes congruent to $4$ modulo $5$.

Comment: Very nice, but not what OP wants.